# Attendance Report using Pivot tables - ELOQUENT

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

What's the best way of handling pivot tables in php/MySQL (or something to that effect), im using RFID tapping for recording their attendance.

i have this two tables:

`Users` table

```
+----------------------------------+
| user_id | first_name | last_name |
| 1       | Tom        | Araya     |
| 2       | Kerry      | King      |
| 3       | Gary       | Holt      |
+----------------------------------+
```

`attendance_log` table

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| log_id | user_id | status   | created_at          | updated_at          |
| 1      | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:08:57 | 2017-08-09 13:08:57 |
| 2      | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:01 | 2017-08-09 13:09:01 |
| 3      | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:15 | 2017-08-09 13:09:15 |
| 4      | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:18 | 2017-08-09 13:09:18 |
| 5      | 3       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:30 | 2017-08-09 13:09:30 |
| 6      | 3       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:33 | 2017-08-09 13:09:33 |
| 7      | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:08:57 | 2017-08-10 13:08:57 |
| 8      | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:01 | 2017-08-10 13:09:01 |
| 9      | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:15 | 2017-08-10 13:09:15 |
| 10     | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:18 | 2017-08-10 13:09:18 |
| 11     | 3       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:30 | 2017-08-10 13:09:30 |
| 12     | 3       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:33 | 2017-08-10 13:09:33 |
| 13     | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-11 13:09:30 | 2017-08-11 13:09:30 |
| 14     | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-11 13:09:33 | 2017-08-11 13:09:33 |
| 15     | 3       | entrance | 2017-08-11 13:10:45 | 2017-08-11 13:10:45 |
| 16     | 3       | entrance | 2017-08-11 13:10:45 | 2017-08-11 13:10:45 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and this the report that i want to achieve

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
| student id | fullname    | Aug 9 | Aug 10 | Aug 11 |
| 1          | Araya, Tom  | P     | P      | A      |
| 2          | King, Kerry | P     | P      | P      |
| 3          | Holt, Gary  | P     | P      | P      |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

how can i do this in eloquent and how to set to `A` if the user does not have an attendance log? Because as of now my attendance report does'nt look like that.
Here's my code

```
    $students = User::has('userStudentAttendance')->with(['userStudentAttendance' => function($query) use ($details,$search_from, $search_to){
        $query->where('status', $details);
        $query->where(function($query) use ($search_from, $search_to){
            $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'), [$search_from, $search_to]);
        });
        $query->groupby('user_id')->groupby(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'));
    }])
    ->leftjoin('sys_user_student', 'sys_user_student.user_id', '=', 'sys_user.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_section', 'sys_mf_section.section_id', '=', 'sys_user_student.section_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_grade', 'sys_mf_grade.grade_id', '=', 'sys_mf_section.grade_id')     
    ->where('user_type_id', '4')
    ->where('sys_mf_section.section_id', $request->getParam('section_id'))
    ->where('sys_mf_grade.grade_id', $request->getParam('grade_id'))    
    ->orderBy('sys_user.last_name') 
    ->get();
```

Comment: Have you attempted a query yet?

Comment: yes @TimBiegeleisen , but i cannot achieve that look

Comment: Also, have you given any thought to your desired output?  Do you know how many days you want in the output, and would you want so many columns for say dozens of days?

Comment: i've updated my post, because my attendance report does have a date range, date from and date to.

Comment: Hi, I know it a bit late, just wonder ave you achieve this? as I am struggled with it as I am able to do in MySQL workbench but fail in PHP